# Getting the Android resource ID for an EditText XML component

Tags: android, xml, resources

I have a few EditText fields in the same XML layout file, I'm using this code but it returns 0 as the id for every EditText field. Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
String resName = "page1entry1";
int resID = resources.getIdentifier(resName, "layout", "mfc.generalgui2");
```

resName is the string id of my EditText field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the wrong label for the second parameter.  It should be this, if you're retrieving an EditText by id:

```
int resID = resources.getIdentifier(resName, "id", "mfc.generalgui2");
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I'm getting the name dynamically (I just didnt show that above since that's not what I needed help with), could you please help using getIdenitifier()?

Comment: Updated answer to match the question.